# Yii autocomplete with dependency on another field

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, yii

I am trying to have a auto complete for two input fields : City and locality . I want the prompt in locality to be based on value in City field : 
This is the current code that I have  :

```
        $this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiAutoComplete', array(
                                 'name'=>'Address[locality]',
                                 'value'=>$Address->locality,
                                 'source'=>CController::createUrl('site/suggestLocation'),
                                 'options'=>array(
                                     'minLength'=>'2',
                                     'focus'=>'js:function( event, ui ) {
                                      $( "#Users_locality" ).val( ui.item.label );
                               return false;
                              }',
                                     'select'=>'js:function( event, ui ) {$("#Users_locality").val( ui.item.label );$("#User_church").val( ui.item.value ); return false; }',
                                 ),
                                 'htmlOptions'=>array(
                                     'class' => 'login_textbox', 'autocomplete'=>'off',
                                 ),
                            ));
```

Comment: did you check by removing 'autocomplete'=>'off', from html options?

Answer (score 0):

In the `focus` javascript event you should add a parameter city to your source url containing the value of the city filled by the user.

Then in the "actionSuggestLocation" method in your controller you handle this parameter:

- Check if the parameter is present
- If it is suggest only locations in the given city
- If it's not then display all the location for example